# How to update live data?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to figure out how to update my live data, I found some examples on Google of Ajax but I can't seem to get them to work.

The part that contains and places the live data in a paragraph is :

```
$file = "Data.txt";
$data = file($file);
$line = $data[count($data)-1];

for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){
    switch ($line) {
    case $i:
    echo "<p class ='bus".$i."'> <img id='bus' src = 'bus.png'> </p>";
    break;
    }
}
```

This is the full html file

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
     <head>
        <title>Bus</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stijlenbestand.css">
    </head>
    <body>  
        <?php
            //aanmaken 5 bushaltes
            echo '<figure>';    
            for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){
                echo "<img src = 'bushalte.png'>";
            }   
            echo '</figure>';

            //laatste lijn van tekstbestand.
            $file = "Data.txt";
            $data = file($file);
            $line = $data[count($data)-1];

            for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){
                switch ($line) {
                case $i:
                echo "<p class ='bus".$i."'> <img id='bus' src = 'bus.png'> </p>";
                break;
                }
            }           
        ?>          
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem... Can you rephrase please?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to update all the `<p class='bus....` lines in real time using the PHP code displayed in the first block of code you posted? Ajax is indeed the answer here, but you say you tried and couldn't get it to work - you should post what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

For a live update you need two parts.

First is the part where your page is and the second part is where your data comes from.

Php is a very static language. Once your script is finished it won't do anything anymore.

For a "live-website" you need Javascript.

if you want to use jQuery i would recommend you to use the jQuery.post() function.

**jQuery Code in your Website:**

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

**Your test.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
  //Do Some Stuff
  $a = 'var a';

  echo json_encode($a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not ajax. Ajax means having frontend code fetching new information on the background. This information then gets appended to the DOM. (Usually the information is transfered as JSON encoded data but lets keep that out of scope.)

For this you need two files:

- A frontend file (for instance static index.html with some content)
- A backend file providing the data

  1. The frontend file would run some JavaScript then requests the backend file
  2. The backend file responds and returns some output
  3. The javascript adds output to the DOM.

There are many ways of doing this and I don't have the te time to explain all of it here but you might want to have a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

This provides a simple example based on jQuery.